# Stretched out image on sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to repeat the image on this code — I'm using `three.js` and covering a sphere with a photo. The photo is very stretched out and pixelated. What can I do?

```js
moonSurface = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(moonRadius -.1, 50, 50), 
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSfk7ndy7wriATp4pCx3fq4q-5yxc_gHrrT3Wf74PFY7n7VCN3T&usqp=CAU')
    })
);

moonSurface.receiveShadow = true;

moon = new THREE.Group();
moon.position.y = -moonRadius;

//floor.add(floorShadow);
moon.add(moonSurface);
scene.add(moon);
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. If you're using [a tiny photo](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSfk7ndy7wriATp4pCx3fq4q-5yxc_gHrrT3Wf74PFY7n7VCN3T&usqp=CAU), it'll be stretched out and pixelated when mapped over a large area. You should show a screenshot of what the problem is, and what you expect it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your photo](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSfk7ndy7wriATp4pCx3fq4q-5yxc_gHrrT3Wf74PFY7n7VCN3T&usqp=CAU) wasn't made to be mapped over an entire sphere, since it's just a tiny crop of the Moon. To properly wrap an image over a sphere without distortions, you'll need an image with an [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection).

Three.js has this image in its examples folder that you might want to use instead:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/textures/planets/moon_1024.jpg